# Jasper server datasource timeout setting

Tags: jasper-reports, postgresql-9.1, jasperserver

I'm using JasperReports Server 4.7 with PostgreSQL 9.1 backend. Trying to set the data source timeout setting but cannot find it in the datasource configuration page. Anyone know where I can set this? I've also searched all the configuration xml files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a JDBC data source (though I'm not certain). But you can certainly set a timeout or a keepalive parameter on a JNDI datasource. Use that instead, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed specify a connection timeout in the jdbc url.

example: `jdbc://server/database?connectTimeout=<TIMEOUT IN MILLISECONDS>`

Check more properties here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html